# Direct output from gnome-terminal to text file

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

Hi I am trying to direct output of my script to a file

My script is

```
gnome-terminal -- ./program +config
```

I have consulted some post and have tried

```
gnome-terminal -- "./program +config 2>&1 | tee output.txt"
```

or

```
gnome-terminal -- 'bash -c "./program +config 2>&1 | tee output.txt"'
```

and many other variations but they do not work well

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Why do you need to involve the terminal at all? `./program +config >output.txt`

Comment: @kusalananda my script have numerous different program running and in other pc ...but I only need to log one of the responses...I will use your solution and run the program as a standalone

Comment: My comment was a question, not really a solution. Why are you involving the terminal? I then suggested the naive way of running the command that you showed with a redirection, not really knowing what the command does or the context in which you use the command.

Comment: @kusalananda I want to see the output of the program on a console..that is why I involve a gnome-terminal....

Comment: What do you mean by »they do not work well«? What does happen oppsed to what you would like to happen?

Comment: @philippos my bad...I actually meant to mean that they do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Correct Answer

It's very likely you don't need to use `gnome-terminal` to achieve whatever you're doing. There most likely is a better way to capture the output of `./program` than running it in gnome-terminal.

### You still want to use gnome-terminal

Unlike other terminals (like Konsole or xterm) I couldn't find any option to log the output of a session. If anything, the Gnome Manual says about the scrollback data:

> Scrollback data is stored in compressed and encrypted files on disk, under the system’s default location for temporary files (usually /tmp). These files are unlinked immediately after their creation, and as such, do not show up in the directory listing. The occupied disk space is freed up as soon as the corresponding terminal closes.

It seems that Gnome is going out of its way to prevent users from getting an output log. You can work around it by using the `script` utility. From the man page:

```
    script - make typescript of terminal session
```

The answer is as simple as launching `script` before running your program.
In other words, replace:

`gnome-terminal -- ./program +config` with `gnome-terminal -- script -f $LOG_FILE -c "./program +config"`.

Make sure to give a proper value to `$LOG_FILE`, something like `LOG_FILE=$HOME/.terminal.log`, and you should find the output in there once the program exits.

Comment: "It seems that Gnome is going out of its way to prevent users from getting an output log" – as a former GNOME Terminal developer, I firmly object to this statement.

First, users requested support for arbitrarily large scrollback buffer, even larger than the amount of RAM. And they also requested that a stolen disk shouldn't contain logs of earlier sessions. The only solution for these two criteria is an encrypted file. The current design is _for_ these often-requested features, not _against_ something.

Comment: Second, a scrollback buffer is a scrollback buffer and lot a logging facility; and a logging facility is a logging facility, not a scrollback buffer. They have quite different technical needs. Just a few, without going to every single detail. Scrollback buffer needs indexing by row number, to allow for fast scrolling by the user. It needs to remember the data that actually scrolled out, which the emitting application might have overwritten plenty of times before scrolling out; it does not (and should not) remember the data that got overwritten on the main screen before getting scrolled out.

Comment: It needs to drop data that's older than the configured amount of scrollback lines, to not grow infinitely if that's not what the user wants. It needs to encode the graphical attributes in some way, ANSI escape sequences being a pretty bad choice for this. Ideally it encodes the text according to a fixed encoding (maybe UCS-32 or UTF-8) rather than the runtime alterable encoding used by the terminal. And so on and so forth. I highly doubt there are any terminal emulators out there which can wash up these two separate concepts (scrollback vs. logging).

Comment: Third, the scrollback's format is internal to gnome-terminal, is not meant to be public. It's subject to change any time without notice, as it has already changed a couple of times to optimize the terminal's performance, to implement a new feature, or to clean up the codebase. Even the number of backing files involved, or the way to locate those files, have changed over time. It was never meant to be a public interface, for these good reasons. If you stripped off the encryption and compression layers, and looked at those files, you still wouldn't be able to reconstruct the session log.

Comment: Logging is an independent story, and even despite the scrollback being stored in encrypted files, logging (in an unencrypted way) could be added easily. Do you think there's a compelling reason for this feature? Given the existence of `script` I doubt so. But maybe you want to bring it up in the issue tracker and see what the developer thinks? Anyway, whatever he thinks, it'll be independent from the (encrypted or not) scrollback story.

Comment: It's by no means an intent of GNOME Terminal to make it hard to debug the data. It's a missing feature, for which I don't see a good reason to implement as there's a tool (not a workaround as you say, but a tool designed to do this), but maybe I'm missing something. Anyway, it has absolutely nothing to do with the scrollback buffer's internal representation. I hope this makes sense and clarifies a lot of things.

Comment: @egmont Thanks for the clarification. I didn't mean to imply that GNOME's decision were unsound or unjustified. I just meant that they took the decision to not log this anywhere. And yes, scrollback isn't logging, but it was the closest thing I found. Anyway, thanks for the clarification :)